# How can i call API periodically?

Tags: java, android

I am working in android. I want to draw a comment window. in which I have a list View which shows comment retrieved from a API.

I want to call that API after 30 second again and again so i can show recent comments in my list view.

This is the code which is used to call my API.

```
HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();                
HttpGet get = new HttpGet("192.168.1.127/CC/comment");
HttpResponse rp = hc.execute(get);

if (rp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) 
{
    //Then put values in some text boxes.
}
```

I want to call this above code again and again after 10 second. Please help me in writing code. Your may give a short example to solve this type of problem. I have very short time and dont have time to search on google so please help how can i call API and change UI periodically ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
I want to call that API after 30 second again and again
```

You Should use **Service** with **Broadcast receiver**.

Service will do your Task in Background but will not provide any UI so you need to register with Broadcast receiver.

[Check this Sample](http://www.websmithing.com/2011/02/) , this sample show how to repeat a task and update UI using Service and Broadcast receiver.

Also [refer this tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidServices/article.html) for further reference.

Answer (score 1):

**You can simply use following code snippet:**

```
// We need to use this Handler package
import android.os.Handler;

// Create the Handler object (on the main thread by default)
Handler handler = new Handler();
// Define the code block to be executed
private Runnable runnableCode = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      // Do something here on the main thread
      Log.d("Handlers", "Called on main thread");
      // Repeat this the same runnable code block again another 2 seconds
      // 'this' is referencing the Runnable object
      handler.postDelayed(this, 2000);
    }
};
// Start the initial runnable task by posting through the handler
handler.post(runnableCode);
```

You can remove the scheduled execution of a runnable with:

// Removes pending code execution

```
handler.removeCallbacks(runnableCode);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem like this:-

```
public class ClassName extends Activity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstance);
        setContentView(R.layout.live_stream_layout);

        handler.post(timedTask);

    private Runnable timedTask = new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            //do your work here for calling API and UI
            handler.postDelayed(timedTask ,2000 );
        }};
```